# Missing number and illegal unit of measurement errors in XeLaTeX because of the titlesec package (at least that's what I think)

Tags: xetex, titlesec

So I'm new to using LaTeX environment and as everyone at the start does, I too have run into some problems. Hoping that you guys could help me out.

I've posted my code below and the errors I'm getting are

1. Missing number treated as zero and
2. Illegal unit of measure

at the each line where a "section" or "subsection" is starting and the funny thing is that it's not affecting the PDF output at all and I'm getting the exact output that I require.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}                           
\usepackage{titlesec}    
\usepackage{fontspec}   
\usepackage{xparse}  
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{subcaption}



\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,SizeFeatures={Size=12}]{Verdana}
\newfontfamily\headingfont{Century Gothic}   
\newfontfamily\sectionfont{Calibri}  
\newfontfamily\subsubsectionfont{Verdana}

% From the package titlesec   
\titleformat*{\section}{\sectionfont\fontsize{26}\selectfont}

\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{}{}{}{}[]  
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\headingfont\fontsize{14}\selectfont\bfseries}



\begin{document}  
\section*{\bfseries{Introduction}}
"""Error here"""



\subsection*{Description:}
"""Error here"""


\subsection*{Settings:}
"""Error here"""

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your use of `\fontsize` doesn't match its definition (second argument and unit missing).

Comment: Btw: You do not want `\section*{\bfseries{Introduction}}`! Remove the second pair of braces and at best the formatting macro too.

Comment: while it's not a latex error it is really wrong to have font commands like `\bfseries` in a section heading, one of the main aims of latex is to separate structural commands like `\section` from the font choice and design (in the document class or preamble)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two errors: `\fontsize` requires *two* arguments (size and baseline skip); `\titleformat{\subsection}` doesn't like all its arguments to be empty (and, besides, you're doing `\titleformat*{\subsection}` anyhow).

I don't think it's a good idea to have four different sans serif fonts in one and the same document. Two is already too much, but in the example below I use a different font (similar to Century Gothic which I don't own) for the section headings.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,SizeFeatures={Size=12}]{Verdana}
\newfontfamily\headingfont{TeX Gyre Adventor}

% From the package titlesec
\titleformat*{\section}{\fontsize{26}{36}\headingfont\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\fontsize{14}{18}\headingfont\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\section*{Introduction}
No error here

\subsection*{Description:}
No error here

\end{document}
```

[image]